# Iterators and Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, iterator

How can i make an `Iterator` point to where I want in my `Hashtable` other than the start?

Let's assume I have

```
Hashtable P = new Hashtable();
P.put("P10", new Integer (10) );
P.put("P11", new Integer (11) );
P.put("P13", new Integer (13) );
P.put("P17", new Integer (17) );
P.put("P15", new Integer (15) );
Set PSet = P.entrySet();
Iterator ptP = Pset.iterator();
```

How can I make the `Iterator` point to `P17` without having to iterate. I would like to write something like in c++, i.e. something like `ptP = P17` so that the pointer or `Iterator` points to that element first.

Comment: please follow Java coding conventions. Variables should always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Even if you could do it, it probably would not do what you want. The iterator does not necessarily iterate in insertion order, unless you use a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: `Hashtable` and `Iterator` are in my opinion outdated java classes. Consider using `HashMap` (or `TreeMap`) and maybe even `Stream` (java8).

Comment: `Hashtable` is obsolete since Java 1.2.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with HashTable or HashMap.

If you can use TreeMap instead of HashTable, you can use :

```
Iterator iter = tailMap("P17",true).entrySet().iterator();
```

This iterator will iterate starting from the entry of "P17".

Comment: I appreciate the quick response! thanks... 
but one more thing i noticed..pls bare with me cos am new to java...
this line 
Integer i = (Integer) P.get("P17"); 

forces "P17" to be treated as an integer ??? 
thanks... because I was not thinking of the keys as integers during implementation but as Strings...
not  that I mind...just want more understanding